Expo when enabling fast refresh a black bar with the words refreshing... keeps flashing
When enabling fast refresh a black bar constantly flickers on the screen while I am developing. Its super distracting and I can't seem to get it to go away. Any way to disable it? Sorry about the bad screenshot but it was really difficult to get it since it flashes so fast.
The app is running on Android where I am seeing this.

